# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log

Tags: python, numpy, logging

I become this expression:
`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log`

while trying this:

```
def fct(a, b, c, d):
    global u1
    global u2
    if np.all(c > 0) and np.all(a > 0) and np.all(u1 != 0) and np.all(u2 != 0):
        return a, c, u1, u2

    u1, u2 = np.log(0.6*c), (math.e**d)**0.5
    F = np.log(a**2) + 6*[math.e**(-b)]/u1 + 3/u2
    print( F )
```

any idea??

Comment: Specify the a,b,c,d parameters' values too, this function gave the message above, pls, to be able to help you

Comment: This condition `np.all(c > 0) and np.all(a > 0) and np.all(u1 != 0) and np.all(u2 != 0)` is exactly the case where none of the operations after the `if` block would fail. That means that, as the code is now, if you reach those operations at least one of them will fail. Maybe those should go within the `if` block?

Comment: Please move your edit from answers to question deleting your answer and editing your question, as it is the common on the SO-n and I'm trying to prevent you from getting downvotes to your "answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message can emerge at two expression your code contains:

```
np.log(0.6*c) and np.log(a**2)
```

in the for loop with:

```
np.random.normal()
```

you will get random numbers at this distribution, whose values will be **negative numbers**.

That's why `np.log(0.6*c` will drop up the error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
```

And as Christoph noted below perfectly we have to be prepared for any `0`, because both `np.log(0.6*0)` and `np.log(0**2)` will result in an error message too.

**Example:**

```
np.random.normal(10,4,100)
```

**Out:**

```
array([ 8.04664247, 14.4991884 , 10.89789303, 13.37593183,  3.29981902,
       16.6316143 , 10.64138342,  4.0459445 , 10.49192082, -3.04538967!!!!!,
       13.30443781,  4.13345961, 12.06508196, 10.4286879 ,  7.39431349,
       12.36789249,  9.20424736, 11.13161087, 12.15404482, 12.69897663,
        9.43633904, 12.77818913,  9.02926639,  4.78638573, 13.13104605,
       12.71197993,  6.1550897 ,  7.18496505,  4.3160573 ,  9.12631992,
        8.52408627, 12.45941119,  5.34780934,  5.7023213 , 13.53096085,
       12.1087058 ,  3.65110834,  5.15466232,  8.78768562, 12.54764999,
       15.12211713,  3.26481809,  9.8623701 , 15.88784306,  5.83355467,
        5.32775214,  8.81188865, 13.21886467,  6.78984216,  8.67260897,
        7.06100605, 13.75314668, 15.56562533, 10.33916552,  7.72745465,
       11.27606127, 11.56813697,  7.03177164, 10.63155512, 11.67072579,
       11.70855769, 10.78372397,  5.11327436, 15.61581808,  9.53446815,
       11.21806808, 11.2235412 ,  7.68339223, 12.71484256,  9.99613038,
       13.51834424,  7.73615596,  8.75145457, 13.02222188,  6.76757021,
       13.03580839, 10.67504642, 15.36110384, 15.66816384, -0.0952157 !!!!!!!! ,
        2.23551198, 11.21584659,  4.37791786,  5.45895529, 15.44411348,
       14.7077441 , 14.52080519,  3.70418827,  5.03132122,  5.24810117,
       16.35309566,  7.08504246,  6.81224092, 14.69274684,  8.43257572,
       12.87468578,  7.01621364,  7.62879265,  7.14646032, 20.16254855])
```

**Stepping into your function inside of `np.log()`**

```
c = np.array([ 8.04664247, 14.4991884 , 10.89789303, 13.37593183,  3.29981902,
       16.6316143 , 10.64138342,  4.0459445 , 10.49192082, -3.04538967,
       13.30443781,  4.13345961, 12.06508196, 10.4286879 ,  7.39431349,
       12.36789249,  9.20424736, 11.13161087, 12.15404482, 12.69897663,
        9.43633904, 12.77818913,  9.02926639,  4.78638573, 13.13104605,
       12.71197993,  6.1550897 ,  7.18496505,  4.3160573 ,  9.12631992,
        8.52408627, 12.45941119,  5.34780934,  5.7023213 , 13.53096085,
       12.1087058 ,  3.65110834,  5.15466232,  8.78768562, 12.54764999,
       15.12211713,  3.26481809,  9.8623701 , 15.88784306,  5.83355467,
        5.32775214,  8.81188865, 13.21886467,  6.78984216,  8.67260897,
        7.06100605, 13.75314668, 15.56562533, 10.33916552,  7.72745465,
       11.27606127, 11.56813697,  7.03177164, 10.63155512, 11.67072579,
       11.70855769, 10.78372397,  5.11327436, 15.61581808,  9.53446815,
       11.21806808, 11.2235412 ,  7.68339223, 12.71484256,  9.99613038,
       13.51834424,  7.73615596,  8.75145457, 13.02222188,  6.76757021,
       13.03580839, 10.67504642, 15.36110384, 15.66816384, -0.0952157 ,
        2.23551198, 11.21584659,  4.37791786,  5.45895529, 15.44411348,
       14.7077441 , 14.52080519,  3.70418827,  5.03132122,  5.24810117,
       16.35309566,  7.08504246,  6.81224092, 14.69274684,  8.43257572,
       12.87468578,  7.01621364,  7.62879265,  7.14646032, 20.16254855])

print(np.log(0.6*c))
```

**Out:**

```
[1.5744293  2.16326705 1.87774385 2.08263134 0.683042   2.30047974
 1.85392487 0.8868894  1.83977989    nan!!!! 2.07727203 0.90828911
 1.97948987 1.83373484 1.48988563 2.00427818 1.70883942 1.89896326
 1.9868364  2.03069579 1.73374247 2.03691412 1.6896455  1.05494996
 2.06415373 2.03171923 1.30645371 1.46116503 0.9515167  1.70033691
 1.63207021 2.01165063 1.16586138 1.23004771 2.09415483 1.98309906
 0.78420515 1.12907599 1.66252576 2.01870777 2.20533276 0.67237842
 1.77790089 2.25472861 1.25280091 1.16210379 1.66527617 2.07081933
 1.40460207 1.64934404 1.44376192 2.11044202 2.23423935 1.82511354
 1.5339539  1.91185638 1.93742888 1.43961306 1.85300085 1.94625801
 1.94949438 1.86721233 1.12101435 2.23745876 1.74408784 1.90670008
 1.90718784 1.52823552 2.03194439 1.79137243 2.09322197 1.53507929
 1.6583943  2.05583165 1.40131649 2.05687444 1.85708328 2.22101297
 2.24080525   nan!!!!! 0.29364465 1.90650203 0.96574761 1.18643181
 2.2264023  2.17754854 2.16475684 0.79863852 1.10485699 1.14704071
 2.28359159 1.44716024 1.40789551 2.17652834 1.62127664 2.04443742
 1.43739808 1.52110397 1.45579155 2.49300123]
/untitled0.py:37: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
```

Comment: As the square function maps any real number on non-negative numbers, a*2 won't be negative. Therefore `c` may contain negative numbers that lead to the error. 
Also be prepared for zero, as the logarithm is defined between (0, inf).
A mathematician :D

Comment: @ChristophSchranz You are perfectly right, on the set of negative numbers, we won't have error with `a**2` of course. But in other special case, what you mentioned yourself as well, if we got `0`, then `0**2` will be `0`, where we will get error with `np.log(0)`. Thus we have to be prepared to zero at `a**2` as well. Thank you for the catch! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be overcome by a simple function to check for values equal to zero with:

```
    def safe_log(col_data):
        return list(map(lambda x: 0 if x == 0 else math.log(x), col_data.values))
```

where `col_data` is a Pandas dataframe column. For example:

```
ln_numbers = safe_log(df['my_column'])
```